# len(bytes(1000)) takes 1000 bytes in memory?

Tags: python

I tested the integer with the following codes:

```
In [10]: bin(5)
Out[10]: '0b101'
In [11]: bytes(5)
Out[11]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Then I checked the length of bytes(5)

```
In [13]: len(bytes(5))
Out[13]: 5

In [14]: len(bytes(1000))
Out[14]: 1000
```

Does it mean that `integer 1000` take `1000` bytes in memory?
And `integer 1000` is `250` times more expensive than "text"?

Comment: "bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized with null bytes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bytes(5)` creates a `bytes` object with 5 bytes, each initialized to `'\x00'` (a null byte). It does not create an integer 5.

The `len` function returns the number of elements in a container object. To check the memory footprint of an object you should instead use the `sys.getsizeof` method:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(bytes(5)) # memory footprint of a bytes object with a length of 5
22
>>> sys.getsizeof(5) # memory footprint of the integer 5
14
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> len(bytes(5))
1
>>> len(bytes(1000))
4
```

I got a different output than yours.

Answer (score 0):

`bytes`'s meaning is different for python2 & python3.

In python2, it just a alias of `str`:

```
bytes(1000) -> '1000' # the length is 4
```

In python3, it initialized with null bytes you specify with the first parameter:

```
bytes(1000) -> b'\x00\x00...' # so the length is 1000.
```

If you just want to know why above code give your above output, that's all.

But, if you just want to know the size of `1000`, you could use `sys.getsizeof(1000)` to get the size of one int.